# randomize date and month but preserve year and time interval

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I am dealing with big data in multiple files. This is part of a larger problem but for simplicity purposes, I am breaking it into parts.

file 1 is stored in df1 and file 2 is stored in df2. I have around 12 files with 3 million records in each..

Both df1 and df2 are related but stored as separate files.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'person_id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                        'date_birth': ['12/30/1961', '05/29/1967', '02/03/1957', '7/27/1959', '01/13/1971'],
                        'date_death': ['07/23/2017','05/29/2017','02/03/2015',np.nan,np.nan]})
df1['date_birth'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['date_birth'])
df1['date_death'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['date_death'])
df1['diff_birth_death'] = df1['date_death'] - df1['date_birth']
df1['diff_birth_death']=df1['diff_birth_death']/np.timedelta64(1,'D')


df2 = pd.DataFrame({'person_id': [1,1,1,2,3],
                    'visit_id':['A1','A2','A3','B1','B2'],
                    'diag_start': ['01/01/2012', '02/25/2017', '02/03/2015', '07/27/2016', '01/13/2011'],
                    'diag_end': ['05/03/2012','05/29/2017','03/03/2015','08/15/2016','02/13/2011']})
df2['diag_start'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['diag_start'])
df2['diag_end'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['diag_end'])
df2['diff_birth_diag_start'] = df2['diag_start'] - df1['date_birth']
df2['diff_birth_diag_end'] = df2['diag_end'] - df1['date_birth']
df2['diff_birth_diag_start']=df2['diff_birth_diag_start']/np.timedelta64(1,'D')
df2['diff_birth_diag_end']=df2['diff_birth_diag_end']/np.timedelta64(1,'D')
```

What I would like to do is

1) randomize/shift the `date` and `month` values but retain the `year` component and `time difference between events` (between birth and death, between birth and diag_start, between birth and diag_end)

2) How to find the date offset value for each subject (no of days to be added/subtracted/randomized) for which condition above is satisfied

In the example below, I have manually added below offsets.

```
person_id 1 = -10 days (incorrect value. you will see below as to why it's incorrect)
person_id 2 = 10 days
person_id 3 = 100 days
person_id 4 = 20 days
person_id 5 = 125 days
```

I expect my output to be something like below

**df1 - all correct - date and months shifted (year and interval is retained)**

[image]

**df2 - offset chosen was incorrect leading to change in year. Though interval was maintained `year` value changed.**

[image]

Comment: I don't know if I understood the question. You have a datetime, say 2000-01-01, then you want to randomize the month and day parts, so that 2000 cannot change, but other parts can, example: 2000-04-28. Is this what you want?

Comment: Yes. you are right. But you should also keep in mind the `time interval` between events. Because it's in a chronological order

Comment: I have given the `time interval` with `date_birth` as a reference to other date columns. If you see my sample data code, you will get an idea

Comment: Does that mean that the interval must be positive, or that it must be strictly the same? Example: if start is 2000-01-01 and end event is 2000-12-31? There are some valid options: 1) Cannot randomize because doing so and keeping interval the same will change either start year or end year 2) Can still randomize, as long as the end event is after the start event, the interval is still positive and both dates can still be 2000... 3) Only the start year and interval must be the same, the end year can change to 2001 for example.

Comment: @MiguelAngelo - You are spot on.. Yes `2000-01-01` and `2000-12-31` is an edge case scenario.  We can stick to option 1. I understand it may not work for edge cases like `2000-01-01` or `2000-12-31` but chances of them occurring are very rare. For non-edge cases as shown above in post, can help me on how it can be done?

Comment: Might we can find a way to flag/highlight edge case scenarios and not apply the logic to them

Comment: I don't think so... the best thing to do I think is to determine the range in which start event can be changed, then the range in which end event can be changed. Get the intersection between ranges, and get any value randomly inside the intersection. That would give a valid result according to option 1... I will have to test the hypotheses.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216141/discussion-between-the-great-and-miguel-angelo).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the comments, what you want is to randomize two `datetime` objects given some restrictions:

1. The start date must be lower than the end date
2. The time interval between start and end dates must remain the same after randomization
3. The start and end years must remain the same (e.g. 2000-01-01 cannot become 1999-12-31)

To solve this problem, what I thought was to find the range of change that is possible for the start data without changing the year, then find the range of change that is possible for the end date, also without changing the year, and finally intersect them to get the range of change that applies to both dates. After that, any random value inside the final range will not change the year of any of the limiting dates and will keep the interval intact.

I have created a function that implements this functionality. You pass it the start and end datetime objects, and it will return a tuple with those dates randomized according to the restrictions.

```
import datetime as dt
from random import random

def rand_date_diff_keep_year_and_interval(dt1, dt2):
    if dt1 > dt2:
        raise Exception("dt1 must be lesser than dt2")
    range1 = {
        "min": dt1.replace(month=1, day=1) - dt1,
        "max": dt1.replace(month=12, day=31) - dt1,
    }
    range2 = {
        "min": dt2.replace(month=1, day=1) - dt2,
        "max": dt2.replace(month=12, day=31) - dt2,
    }
    intersection = {
        "min": max(range1["min"], range2["min"]),
        "max": min(range1["max"], range2["max"]),
    }
    rand_change = random()*(intersection["max"] - intersection["min"]) + intersection["min"]
    return (dt1 + rand_change, dt2 + rand_change)

print(rand_date_diff_keep_year_and_interval(dt.datetime(2000, 1, 1), dt.datetime(2000, 12, 31)))
print(rand_date_diff_keep_year_and_interval(dt.datetime(2000, 5, 18), dt.datetime(2001, 8, 20)))
```

### Pandas Solution

To work with Pandas DataFrame we need to adapt the previous code to work with series instead of single datetime objects. The logic stays almost the same, but now we are doing everything "series-wise" so to speak. Also, I used `numpy.random` to generate a series of random number, instead of creating just one random number and repeat it for all rows... that would be a lot less random.

```
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd
import numpy.random as rnd

def series_rand_date_diff_keep_year_and_interval(sdt1, sdt2):
    if any(sdt1 > sdt2):
        raise Exception("dt1 must be lesser than dt2")
    range1 = {
        "min": sdt1.apply(lambda dt1: dt1.replace(month=1, day=1) - dt1),
        "max": sdt1.apply(lambda dt1: dt1.replace(month=12, day=31) - dt1),
    }
    range2 = {
        "min": sdt2.apply(lambda dt2: dt2.replace(month=1, day=1) - dt2),
        "max": sdt2.apply(lambda dt2: dt2.replace(month=12, day=31) - dt2),
    }
    intersection = {
        "min": pd.concat([range1["min"], range2["min"]], axis=1).max(axis=1),
        "max": pd.concat([range1["max"], range2["max"]], axis=1).min(axis=1),
    }
    rand_change = pd.Series(rnd.uniform(size=len(sdt1)))*(intersection["max"] - intersection["min"]) + intersection["min"]
    return (sdt1 + rand_change, sdt2 + rand_change)

df = pd.DataFrame([
        {"start": dt.datetime(2000, 1, 1), "end": dt.datetime(2000, 12, 31)},
        {"start": dt.datetime(2000, 5, 18), "end": dt.datetime(2001, 8, 20)},
    ])

df2 = pd.DataFrame(df)
df2["start"], df2["end"] = series_rand_date_diff_keep_year_and_interval(df["start"], df["end"])
print(df2.head())
```

### Multicolumn Pandas Solution

Looking again at the question, there are many columns in the sequence of events, all of them representing dates, and some of them of NaT values (null dates). If we want the same restrictions to apply, and keep the relative distance between all events in the series of events, without changing the year of any of the values, and also accepting NaT columns, we have to change a few things. Instead of listing the changes, lets go straight into the code:

```
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd
import numpy.random as rnd
import numpy as np
from functools import reduce

def manyseries_rand_date_diff_keep_year_and_interval(*sdts):
    ranges = list(map(
        lambda sdt:
            {
                "min": sdt.apply(lambda dt: dt.replace(month=1,  day=1 ) - dt),
                "max": sdt.apply(lambda dt: dt.replace(month=12, day=31) - dt),
            },
        sdts
        ))
    intersection = reduce(
        lambda range1, range2:
            {
                "min": pd.concat([range1["min"], range2["min"]], axis=1).max(axis=1),
                "max": pd.concat([range1["max"], range2["max"]], axis=1).min(axis=1),
            },
        ranges
        )
    rand_change = pd.Series(rnd.uniform(size=len(intersection["max"])))*(intersection["max"] - intersection["min"]) + intersection["min"]
    return list(map(lambda sdt: sdt + rand_change, sdts))

def setup_diffs(df1, df2):
    df1['diff_birth_death'] = df1['date_death'] - df1['date_birth']
    df1['diff_birth_death'] = df1['diff_birth_death']/np.timedelta64(1,'D')

    df2['diff_birth_diag_start'] = df2['diag_start'] - df1['date_birth']
    df2['diff_birth_diag_end'] = df2['diag_end'] - df1['date_birth']
    df2['diff_birth_diag_start'] = df2['diff_birth_diag_start']/np.timedelta64(1,'D')
    df2['diff_birth_diag_end'] = df2['diff_birth_diag_end']/np.timedelta64(1,'D')

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'person_id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                        'date_birth': ['12/30/1961', '05/29/1967', '02/03/1957', '7/27/1959', '01/13/1971'],
                        'date_death': ['07/23/2017', '05/29/2017', '02/03/2015', np.nan,      np.nan]})
df1['date_birth'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['date_birth'])
df1['date_death'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['date_death'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'person_id': [1,1,1,2,3],
                    'visit_id':['A1','A2','A3','B1','B2'],
                    'diag_start': ['01/01/2012', '02/25/2017', '02/03/2015', '07/27/2016', '01/13/2011'],
                    'diag_end': ['05/03/2012','05/29/2017','03/03/2015','08/15/2016','02/13/2011']})
df2['diag_start'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['diag_start'])
df2['diag_end'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['diag_end'])
setup_diffs(df1, df2)

display(df1)
display(df2)

series_list = manyseries_rand_date_diff_keep_year_and_interval(
    df1['date_birth'], df1['date_death'], df2['diag_start'], df2['diag_end'])
df1['date_birth'], df1['date_death'], df2['diag_start'], df2['diag_end'] = series_list
setup_diffs(df1, df2)

display(df1)
display(df2)
```

This time, I used Jupyter Notebook to better visualize the DataFrames:

[image: Final result showing the Jupyter Notebook visualization of the DataFrames]

Hope this helps! Any comments and suggestion are welcome.

Comment: Hi @Miguel Angelo!! Thanks for your response,Upvoted. How can we pass our dataframe to the function? Because my input data is million plus rows

Comment: Hey... sorry, forgot you were using a Pandas DataFrame. I added a Pandas solution to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your effort and time. Though I am not able to get the exact output, I still mark as answer for your effort and time. Appreciate it

Comment: Sure, thnks, I will create another post tomo and link here

Comment: I'm reading the question again... I thought there were only two dates, but there are many events. I will try to update the answer to reflect that. Adding more dates to the equation is not that difficult, it will be an intersection of the ranges for all dates in the sequence of events.

Comment: can help me with this?   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62635778/exclude-a-specific-date-based-on-a-condition-using-pandas