# Exclude a specific date based on a condition using pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'person_id':[11,11,11,11,11,12,12,13,13,14,14,14,14],
                    'admit_date':['01/01/2011','01/01/2009','12/31/2013','12/31/2017','04/03/2014','08/04/2016',
                                  '03/05/2014','02/07/2011','08/08/2016','12/31/2017','05/01/2011','05/21/2014','07/12/2016']})
df2 = df2.melt('person_id', value_name='dates')
df2['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['dates'])
```

What I would like to do is

a) Exclude/filter out records from the data frame if a subject has `Dec 31st` and `Jan 1st` in its records. Please note that `year` doesn't matter.

If a subject has **either `Dec 31st` or `Jan 1st`, we leave them as is**.

But if they have both `Dec 31st` and `Jan 1st`, we remove one (either Dec 31st or Jan 1st) of them. note they could have multiple entries with the same date as well. Like `person_id = 11`

I could only do the below

```
df2_new =  df2['dates'] != '2017-12-31'  #but this excludes if a subject has only `Dec 31st on 2017`. How can I ignore the dates and not consider `year`
df2[df2_new]
```

My expected output is like as shown below

[image]

For person_id = 11, we drop `12-31` because it had both `12-31` and `01-01` in their records whereas for person_id = 14, we don't drop `12-31` because it has only `12-31` in its records.

We drop `12-31` only when **both `12-31` and `01-01`** appear in a person's records.

Comment: Is possible add more general solution for pairs 31.12 and 1.1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
s = df2['dates'].dt.strftime('%m-%d')
m1 = s.eq('01-01').groupby(df2['person_id']).transform('any')
m2 = s.eq('12-31').groupby(df2['person_id']).transform('any')
m3 = np.select([m1 & m2, m1 | m2], [s.ne('12-31'), True], default=True)
df3 = df2[m3]
```

Result:

```
# print(df3)
    person_id    variable      dates
0          11  admit_date 2011-01-01
1          11  admit_date 2009-01-01
4          11  admit_date 2014-04-03
5          12  admit_date 2016-08-04
6          12  admit_date 2014-03-05
7          13  admit_date 2011-02-07
8          13  admit_date 2016-08-08
9          14  admit_date 2017-12-31
10         14  admit_date 2011-05-01
11         14  admit_date 2014-05-21
12         14  admit_date 2016-07-12
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216949/discussion-on-answer-by-shubham-sharma-exclude-a-specific-date-based-on-a-condit).

Answer (score 1):

Another way

Coerce the date to day month.
Create temp column where `31st Dec` is converted to `1st Jan`
Drop duplicates by `Person id` and the `temp column` keeping first.

```
 df2['dates']=df2['dates'].dt.strftime('%d %b')
df2=df2.assign(check=np.where(df2.dates=='31 Dec','01 Jan', df2.dates)).drop_duplicates(['person_id', 'variable', 'check'], keep='first').drop(columns=['check'])



 person_id    variable   dates   check
0          11  admit_date  01 Jan  01 Jan
4          11  admit_date  03 Apr  03 Apr
5          12  admit_date  04 Aug  04 Aug
6          12  admit_date  05 Mar  05 Mar
7          13  admit_date  07 Feb  07 Feb
8          13  admit_date  08 Aug  08 Aug
9          14  admit_date  31 Dec  01 Jan
10         14  admit_date  01 May  01 May
11         14  admit_date  21 May  21 May
12         14  admit_date  12 Jul  12 Jul
```

Comment: for subject 11, we should be able to see another `jan 1st` record as shown in expected output.. Upvoted for the response

Comment: Please calriffy, will you accept any other dates, duplicated say 2nd May

Comment: Can I kindly check with you on why will there be duplicates?

Comment: I have logic to achieve what you need. You want to drop dates as per given instruction above. In your datasets, is there a possibility of other dates being duplicated?

Comment: If you are asking whether in my dataset the dates can be duplicated. Yes, it can have duplicates for the same subject.

Comment: Ha vent found outlet yet, keep trying